# Mac Osx insert text into a created file using sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, console, sh

I am creating an .sh file on my mac console.

```
myshfile.sh
```

From inside my .sh file I have created a file:

So:

```
touch index.js
```

So on a whole I do this to run it:

```
sh myshfile.sh
```

My question is. How can I insert some text inside the index.js for example:

```
console.log('hello from index.js');
```

...for the sh command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use >> redirect to append or just > if you want to overwrite the previous content of the file.

```
$ touch index.js
$ echo "console.log('hello from index.js');" >> index.js
$ cat index.js
console.log('hello from index.js');
```

Comment: The `touch` command doesn't remain necessary; `index.js` will be created if necessary when the shell opens it with `>>`.